# Failed to load PDF document - Angular 8

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, pdf

I am trying to open a PDF in another browser tab using Angular 8. The PDF is returned by a Spring boot API as a byte array:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> beve(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(service.getPdf(request), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

On the Angular side, for the service:

```
  getPdf(): any {
    const httpOptions = {
      'responseType' : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
    };

    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + "/pdf", httpOptions);
  }
```

And the component that is calling it:

```
getPdf() {
    this.service.getPdf().subscribe((response => {
      const file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });

      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, "app.pdf");
      } else {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL);
      }
    }));
  }
```

However, when the PDF opens up in a new tab, I get this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: change responseType To "blob"

Comment: if still doesn't work provide a stackblitz.

Comment: @AakashGarg Change it in which line exactly? In the httpOptions or the new Blob line?

Comment: in httpOptions.

Comment: @AakashGarg Thanks, I will try

Comment: and remove as json with it. just keep "blob"

Comment: @AakashGarg Okay

Comment: @AakashGarg It doesn't work unless you have the "as json". It gives a syntax error otherwise.

Comment: What error? Please post above?

Comment: @AakashGarg Looks like a bug report has been submitted already: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

Comment: can you give a stackblitz?

Comment: blob works, see this stackblitz i create :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6qwrvh

Comment: I am also facing the same, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced similar situation. try converting array buffer into base64 string and it is working fine in all browsers.

```
var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data.data)));
var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64String;
windoe.open(pdfAsDataUri);
```